# Electric Field on Dielectic Material

Tags: electricity

I found the electric field in the first shape but İf ı cover plates with High dielectric strength material, what happens to electric field?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how thick the coating is. If it is very thin there will be no considerable change. However if it is thick the portion of coating coming in between the plates will develop induced field in opposite direction thereby reducing the electric field in the region where the dielectric is present only. Region between plates with no dielectric will have same previous value of electric field

Comment: Thank you. What about insulators? What happens if ı use an insulator?

Comment: Actually all dielectrics are quite good insulators. By definition, dielectrics are electrical insulators which get polarised in presence of electric fields. So by using a dielectric you are also using a insulator. The amount of reduction of electric field in side the insulating material depends on its polarisability(measured in terms electric susceptibility of a material). However the insulating property of a dielectric might breakdown in very high power electric fields. Ability to withstand huge electric fields without losing insulating prop is measured by a materials dielectric strength.